# Azure Automation or Azure Function when creating an Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-automation

We are creating a SaaS application, where each client has it's own database.  I would like to automate the creation of the clients environment, which will be triggered from our website.

I am investigating using either Azure Automation or Azure Functions to create our client databases.

If anyone has some experience with these tools, I would appreciate your input.

Regards
Remeez

Comment: Just curious, why can't you simply use Azure SDK (which is a wrapper around Azure REST API) to create databases on the fly?

Comment: Thanks, maybe I am over complicating my solution.  I will look into using the Azure SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified any constraints that you have, so there are many ways to do that. One scenario could be:

1. Send a message to a Queue from your website.
2. Create an Azure Function which will listen to that queue, and run a script to create a new database.

Make sure that your database creation is below 5 minutes (10 minutes max), otherwise you won't be able to use Consumption Plan for Function App.

Answer (score 1):

If the databases will have the same schema for all customers, you can have an empty database that works as a template, and then issue a CREATE DATABASE AS COPY specifying the tier of the new database.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy   
    AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P2' )  ;
```

Consider using elastic pools which have elastic jobs than can later help you automate common tasks on all customer databases. With elastic pools you can create copies of databases also.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy   
    AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original   
    (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL( name = ep1 ) ) ;
```

You can also create a database or a copy of a database using REST API as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases/CreateOrUpdate).